# React groupBy and print into table

Tags: arrays, reactjs, sorting, lodash

EDITED:
methods groupBy, omit and mapValue are imported from:

```
import groupBy from 'lodash/groupBy';
import mapValues from 'lodash/mapValues';
import omit from 'lodash/omit';
```

I have this json

```
[{
    "name": "Jitka",
    "orderNumber": "1",
    "order": false
},
{
    "name": "Jitka",
    "orderNumber": "0",
    "order": false
},
{
    "name": "Petr",
    "orderNumber": "6",
    "order": false
}]
```

In react I need group value by name. And after grouping I need data print into table in format

[image]
The problem is, how convert this data, which I groupBy name into table in this format.

My code is:

```
{
        const ordersByName = groupBy(this.state && this.state.orders, 'name');
        let order = mapValues(ordersByName, x => x.map(y => omit(y, 'name')));
        this.state.sortedOrders.push(order);

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <MyNavbar/>
            <div className="container">
                <table className="table">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Order number</th>
                        <th>Order</th>
                    </tr>
                    {this.state.sortedOrders.map((offer) => {
                        console.log(offer);

                    })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is `groupBy`? where is implemented?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data needs to be reduced first since you are essentially grouping on `orderNumber`. So since you are already using lodash you can try doing this:

```
let data = _(this.state.sortedOrders) // <-- chain this array via _.chain
  .groupBy('name')  // <-- group by name first
  .mapValues(arr =>  // <-- map through the values of the object from groupBy
    _.mergeWith(  // <-- merge the grouped by name records
      ..._.sortBy(arr, 'orderNumber'),  // <-- sort the array by `orderNumber`
      (o, s, k) => _.isEqual(k, 'orderNumber') ? o + (s ? ',' + s : '') : o)
  )
  .values() // <-- get the values of the final object
  .value()  // <-- get the final result from the chaining
```

And then your render would be:

```
<div>
  <MyNavbar/>
  <div className="container">
    <table className="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Order number</th>
          <th>Order</th>
        </tr>
        {data.map(offer => (
        <tr>
            <td>{offer.name}</td>
            <td>{offer.orderNumber}</td>
            <td>{offer.order}</td>
        </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The short story is that you need to get your `data` to look like the result of this:

```js
let data = [{ "name": "Jitka", "orderNumber": "1", "order": false }, { "name": "Jitka", "orderNumber": "0", "order": false }, { "name": "Petr", "orderNumber": "6", "order": false } ]

let result = _(data)
  .groupBy('name')
  .mapValues(arr =>
    _.mergeWith(
      ..._.sortBy(arr, 'orderNumber'),
      (o, s, k) => _.isEqual(k, 'orderNumber') ? o + (s ? ',' + s : '') : o)
  )
  .values()  
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see you have 2 records instead of your initial 3 since we merged two of them by `orderNumber`.

This can obviously be done with Array.reduce/Array.sort etc but since you already are using lodash you can simply utilize its `groupBy/mergeWith` etc functions.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses [`_.flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) to create a combine groups function. The function accepts an iteratee (whatever [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) can use as iteratee), and a list of keys that should be collected as arrays. The result is a new function that can group by the iteratee, and then merge each group, and combine the values of whatever keys are in `collectKeys`:

```js
const { flow, partialRight: pr, groupBy, map, mergeWith } = _; // simulates separate imports

const combineGroups = (iteratee, collectKeys) => flow(
  pr(groupBy, iteratee),
  pr(map, group => mergeWith({}, ...group, (t = [], s, k) => 
    collectKeys.includes(k) ? [...t, s] : s)
  )
);

const combineGroupsByName = combineGroups('name', ['orderNumber']);

const Demo = ({ orders }) => {
  const ordersByName = combineGroupsByName(orders);

  return (
    <div className="container">
        <table className="table">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Order number</th>
                <th>Order</th>
            </tr>
            {ordersByName.map(({ name, orderNumber, order }) => (
              <tr>
                  <td>{name}</td>
                  <td>{orderNumber.sort().join(', ')}</td>
                  <td>{order.toString()}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  );
};

const orders = [{"name":"Jitka","orderNumber":"1","order":false},{"name":"Jitka","orderNumber":"0","order":false},{"name":"Petr","orderNumber":"6","order":false}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo orders={orders} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```